# Problems Creating an Infinite Lazy List

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I completed the seventh Euler problem* in F# but am not entirely happy with my 
implementation. In the function `primes` I create a sequence that I estimated would contain the 10,001st prime number. When I tried using Seq.initInfinite to lazily generate the candidate primes my code just hung before throwing an out of memory exception.

Could someone advise me on replacing the literal sequence with a lazily-generated sequence which is short-circuited once the desired prime is found?

```
let isPrime n =
    let bound = int (sqrt (float n))
         seq {2 .. bound} |> Seq.forall (fun x -> n % x <> 0)

let primeAsync n =
    async { return (n, isPrime n)}  

let primes =
    {1..1000000}
         |> Seq.map primeAsync
         |> Async.Parallel
         |> Async.RunSynchronously
         |> Array.filter snd
         |> Array.map fst
         |> Array.mapi (fun i el -> (i, el))    
         |> Array.find (fun (fst, snd) -> fst = 10001)

primes
```

*"By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13. What is the 10,001st prime number?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is/was that Async.RunSynchronously isn't lazy and tried to evaluate the whole infinite sequence. Although there are better solutions for this, your algorithm is fast enough, so you don't even need parallelization; this works perfectly:

```
open System

let isPrime n =
    let bound = n |> float |> sqrt |> int
    seq {2 .. bound} |> Seq.forall (fun x -> n % x <> 0)

let prime =   
   Seq.initInfinite ((+) 2)
      |> Seq.filter isPrime
      |> Seq.skip 10000
      |> Seq.head
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence gets 'reified' as soon as you feed it to `Async.Parallel`. If you want to minimise memory consumption, run the computation serially or split it into lazy chunks, the elements in each chunk to be run in parallel.